# Characters < and > in sprintf() for send email

Tags: php, email, printf

I have a problem in PHP but I can not seem to find an explanation for this.

I have a simple sprintf to compose an email body:

```
$message = sprintf( 'Order %1$s received. P.O. Box %2$s', 10258, 'My company <order@mycompany.com>' );
```

In the email body only the part of the email address "My company " is displayed. The part of the email address until the < character is displayed. I can not use the html entities.

My solution is to remove the characters < and > in the email address. Is there a better solution?

PHP Version: 7.2.19 (Zend: 3.2.0)

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Which MIME type is used for the mail body? Angle brackets have a specific meaning in HTML context.

Comment: PD of [PHP string doesn't allow < and > characters](//stackoverflow.com/q/8207029) (for lack of [mcve])

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to be more specific with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The MIME type is text/plain.

Comment: It's not a problem of the PHP mail () function. It's a problem of my framework that I use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

since these special characters are stripped. now,

- you can remove those (based on your solution)
- replace < by `&lt;` and > by `&gt;` (bad solution)
- use `htmlspecialchars()` (recommended)

Comment: If i use htmlspecialchars() i get the &lt; and &gt;. In the email body, the characters &lt; and &gt; are shown, not the < and >.

Comment: @Ruddiger, what is your email sender? proximately all of the email-senders have an options name htmlBody and textBody, you must set your email body in the htmlBody to resolve all HTML entities

Comment: Es ist kein Problem von der PHP-Funktion mail (). Es ist ein Problem von meinem Framework, das ich benutze. Vielen Dank m3hr24d.

Comment: It's not a problem of the PHP mail () function. It's a problem of my framework that I use. Thank you m3hr24d